# save website when creating a bookmark

Tags: browser, browser-addons, browser-plugin

I'm saving lots of bookmarks but the websites change when I revisit them days or month later.

Is there a way to save the entire page automatically when making a bookmark so that I will get an option the next time I open the bookmark to show the old version?

Answer (score 1):

Save as a Web Archive, as opposed to a bookmark. Bookmarks only store the location of a web page & each time you visit you see the latest version.

This may be browser-dependant, but a Web Archive will store the full content of the page at the exact moment you saved it. Bear in mind that can be quite large if there's a lot of imagery etc & also that any interactive aspect will not work.

examples [one before this answer, one after] -

[image]

[image]

*After comments*
As far as I can determine, this method does not rely on any caching, nor on being able to reconnect to the original URL.
To test… I went to a page I have never before visited, using a different computer. There I saved a web archive of the page. I passed it back to my own computer, disabled all external connections & opened it. Perfect recall of the page I had just visited on an entirely different machine. Therefore, I'd suggest it is in fact a complete archive of the page as of that moment & requires no re-establishment of any connection nor recourse to any cache to display it.

Comment: It's not browser dependent, except as to what it's called. Chrome calls it "Web Page, single file" or "Web Page, complete" (two different formats; the former is one .mhtml file, the other is one .html file plus a folder with other resources in it), Firefox calls it "Web Page, complete" (same as Chrome version), Edge (being Chromium based) has the same options as Chrome. Bookmarks, in any case, are just pointers to the URL, not copies of the page.

Comment: @JeffZeitlin - The images you see above are not pointers - though if you open them in a browser they do actually go to the URL so you get some odd interactivity, as it's out of sync with the current page. I don't have the chops to examine its contents, it looks like some combination of XML & binary data, but it is to all intents & purposes self-contained. There's reams & reams of such as this - https://i.stack.imgur.com/iACRb.png It works even if I deny it all outgoing connections.

Comment: @tetujin - Imgur is blocked from my job, so I can't see your images.

Comment: I'm not really sure how I'm expected to respond to that - so your comment is based on only the text of my answer & not the images clarifying it? Perhaps better to wait til you get home then ;)

Comment: It's not based only on your answer text, but on many years of experience using computers and browsers. Saving bookmarks may save _metadata_ about the site, so that it knows whether it can use the browser cache for some or all resources, a bookmark is just that - a quick way of getting to the actual location, not a copy of the page.

Comment: @JeffZeitlin - As a further test… I went to a page I have never before visited, on a different computer. There I saved a web archive of the page. I passed it back to my own computer, still with all external connections disabled & opened it. Perfect recall of the page I had just visited on an entirely different machine. Therefore, I'd suggest it is in fact a complete archive of the page as of that moment & requires no re-establishment of any connection nor recourse to any cache to display it.

Comment: This works but has a big problem. Now you end up with a bunch of "website files" in a folder which is not user friendly.  Is there not a way to "combine" it to automatically save as archive too when making a bookmark?

Comment: No, none at all. They are totally different things. One is simply an address, a few bytes in size, the other is a save of the entire page as it was when you saved.